# Floating point comparison on generic property

Tags: c#, generics, floating-point

i have a generic class with some properties:

```
class MyClass<TValueType>
    where TValueType : struct, IComparable
{        
    public TValueType Target
    {
        get { return _target; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_target, value)) return;
            _target = value;
            RaiseTargetChanged(value);
        }
    }

    // Other stuff ...
}
```

As you see i compare with `object.Equals` to avoid excessive event invokes. However, i have an extension method for floating point comparison i would like to use if `TValueType` is double, float or decimal:

```
public static bool AlmostEqual(this double x, double y, double delta = 0.00001d)
public static bool AlmostEqual(this float x, float y, float delta = 0.00001f)
public static bool AlmostEqual(this decimal x, decimal y, decimal delta = 0.00001m)
```

Do should i type compare and cast TValueType and make the proper floating point comparison, or is there a smarter way?

**EDIT: Solution by David Heffernan:**

I've made it mandatory to pass a comparer to the class:

```
class MyClass<TValueType>
{
    public MyClass(IComparer<TValueType> comparer) { ... }
}
```

and then i pass a custom comparer:

```
public class FloatingPointComparer : IComparer<double>, IComparer<float>, IComparer<decimal>, IComparer
{
    public int Compare(double x, double y)
    {
        return FloatingComparisonExtensions.CompareTo(x, y);
    }
    // Rest of Compares are the same
}
```

I'm using a `IComparer` instead of an `IEqualityComparer` since i need to verify Target against a Maximum and Minimum value.

Comment: You could allow the consumer of the class to provide a comparer. Type checking feels pretty unclean and introduces rather heavy coupling.

Comment: D'oh.. I completly forgot about the IComparer<>. Just tested, and that solved my problem! Make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having type checking code in your generic class, which feels somewhat dirty, you could ask the consumer to supply an [`IEqualityComparer<TValueType>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface to perform the comparison. If the consumer does not provide one then the code would default to `Object.Equals`.